# How can I know the list of files added to an SVN branch?

Tags: svn, version-control

I need to find out all the files that were added to a given branch starting from a certain revision number. What command should I use ? I have access to grep, etc. I'm looking for a command-line command, of course. I tried to use `svn log --quiet` but I could not figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "svn diff -r799:HEAD --summarize" provides what you want. Just filter lines starting from "A".

(799 is just a revision when I created branch which was used for testing)